# Laravel 5 Form Request manually specify field name to be displayed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel's form request, how can I manually assign the field name to be displayed on error?

This is my blade.php file

```
<input type="text" name="txtConfigKey" id="txtConfigKey" class="form-control" placeholder="Config Key" />
```

Then on my request file:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'txtConfigKey' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Then the output is: "The txt config key field is required."

Notice that it converted the "txtConfigKey" with spaces. Is there a way for me to manually specify what would the field be?

In CodeIgniter, I can do something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtConfigKey', 'Config Key', 'required');
```

Wherein the first parameter is the name of the field and the second parameter is the name of the field that I want to be displayed on the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using form request then there is a method called messages().
You have to override it with your custom error messages like:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
    'txtConfigKey.required'=>'The Config Key is required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I see.. Is there a shorter way to do this? Just like how codeigniter implemented theirs? Doing this makes me rewrite the codes all over again. Makes my eyes hurt seeing a lot of lines. Also, if a field has multiple rules like `required|array`, would it be `txtKeyConfigKey.required.array`?

Comment: Also, is it really the whole message that we could alter? What if I just want to customize just the field and retain the message the same? Something like `sprintf('The %s is required.')` ?

Comment: You can use Validator class then, It has a static method like    Validator::make($input,$rules,$messages)